# How to insert string after matching patterns

Tags: shell

I have a number of files with contents in the following format:

```
Class ABC
{
  ...

  function getname(userid)
  {
    ...
    ...
  }

  function getprice(itemid,colorcode)
  {
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

and I want to add test points to the files to check if the function has been called, so, the new file should look like, assume the file name for this example is /var/www/html/test.php:

```
Class ABC
{
  ...

  function getname(userid)
  {
    echo /var/www/html/test.php getname(userid) is called
    ...
  }

  function getprice(itemid,colorcode)
  {
    echo /var/www/html/test.php getprice(itemid,colorcode) is called
    ...
  }
}
```

The string "echo {file name} {function name} is called" is to be added to the beginning of each function in the file.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) solution:

```
$ txr addecho.txr data
Class ABC
{
  ...

  function getname(userid)
  {
    echo /var/www/html/test.php getname(userid) is called
    ...
    ...
  }

  function getprice(itemid,colorcode)
  {
    echo /var/www/html/test.php getprice(itemid,colorcode) is called
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Code in `addecho.txr`:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
  function @name(@args)
  {
@    (output)
  function @name(@args)
  {
    echo /var/www/html/test.php @name(@args) is called
@    (end)
@  (or)
@line
@    (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Contents of `data` are just verbatim from the question.